# what is this series: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,

Tags: recursion, series

this is series i'm trying to solve, like come up with a closed from formula.

it follows this program:

```
function(n):
  if(n<=1): 
    return 1
  else if(n%3==0): 
    return function(n+1) - 1
  else:
    return function(n-2) + 1
```

a0 = 1

a1 = 1

a2 = 2

a3 = 2

a4 = 3

a5 = 3

a6 = 3

a7 = 4
... and so on. seems like for the first 4 terms its just 1 1 , 2 2, but then it repeats in 3. so when ever it hits n mod 3 = 1, it starts a new number.

can some one assist me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably belongs to math section.

you can write the series as

```
f(3k)   = f(3k+1) - 1 = f(3k-1)
f(3k+1) = f(3k-1) + 1 = f(3k) + 1
f(3k+2) = f(3k) + 1
```

here you can see that at the values of 3k+1 (4,7,...) the value increments by one and same.  The first pattern is due to initial conditions you set for <=1 values.

You can replace the function with `2+int((k-1)/3)` for k>2.